# AngularJS: OrderBy Filter on Option Select

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-orderby

I'm making a small application that sorts a list of points that users have similar to a game leaderboard. I've set up an ng-repeat over an array of objects and an ng-show on different option selects to show a span within the list. The spans show different point scores.

I've added a orderBy filter on the ng-repeat so the list is filtered from largest to smallest. For instance, when the option select of 'Threads Created' is chosen, then the scores for 'Post Read' and 'Posts Replied' are hidden and the list is sorted by the number of Threads Created (largest to smallest).

It works for two of the option values but not the third. Any idea why?

```
              <tr ng-repeat="user in users | orderBy:['-created','-read','-replied']">
            <td> {{user.index}} </td>
            <td> {{user.firstName}} {{user.lastName}}</td>
            <td>
              <span ng-show='discussionsSelect == "created"'>{{ user.created }}</span>
              <span ng-show='discussionsSelect == "read"'>{{ user.read }}</span>
              <span ng-show='discussionsSelect == "replied"'>{{ user.replied }}</span>
            </td>
          </tr>
```

Comment: Can you replicate the issue in a plunker or jsfiddle? Also, Please post some of the code behind this?

Comment: why do you think is not working? can you post a list snipped and the ordered list?

Comment: Would need to see the data. The third item in your orderBy will only ever come into play when the first two items are identical. Perhaps you don't have any data where that is the case.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to post the plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/Nay1SeNjWcg30OLz73xI?p=preview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm understanding this correctly you are not doing this properly. Your list will only ever be sorted by 'created'. The second value of the orderBy clause will only come into play if two objects with the same 'created' are found. Likewise for the third value in your orderBy clause. It will only ever be used if two items have the same 'created' and then the same 'read' value.
You're going to need to make orderBy a variable that gets set based on the pulldown chosen. You can set it to the name of the variable that your select is bound to. I think that is discussionsSelect in your plnkr.

```
        <tr ng-repeat="user in users | discussionsSelect">
```

Comment: it should be `<tr ng-repeat="user in users | orderBy: '-'+discussionsSelect">`

Comment: Thank you. @UlanMurzatayev - that orderBy filter worked.